# bcrypt.compare with Promise always return false

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, bcrypt

I'm new to Express.js and Passport.js, so probably I'm doing something wrong since bcrypt comapre function always return false.

```
public static findUser = async ({ email, password }) => {
  const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(CommonConstants.connectionString).connect();
  const request = pool.request();
  const result = await request
    .input("Email", sql.NVarChar, email)
    .execute("FindUserSP");
  const user = result.recordset;
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].Password) ? user : {};
};
```

That's how hash was created:

```
const password = req.body.Password;
const email = req.body.Email;
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
```

Test case:

```
Hash: $2b$10$nK1.wW71NcBIQkMQq6wpHe/HMhCjOaQNy9BpfPDef01
password: 123
version: 3.0.2
```

Comment: Do you realize that `return user;` doesn't ever return `user` to anything?

Comment: @CodyG., yes, that's why updated.

Comment: Okay, so what's a test case for password and user[0].Password ? What bycrypt version ?

Comment: Hash: $2b$10$nK1.wW71NcBIQkMQq6wpHe/HMhCjOaQNy9BpfPDef01, password: 123, version: 3.0.2

Comment: `$2b$` ... hmmm

Comment: @CodyG., please see update - how hash was created.

Comment: Check your database isn't CHAR(50) ... (https://repl.it/@CodyGeisler/bcrypt-test?language=nodejs works fine for me)

Comment: @CodyG., no, it's nvarchar(100).

Comment: The hash I get is always 59-60 characters. Why is the one you provided 50?

Comment: Yeah, altough it's working fine on repl.it. May it very depending on OS?

Comment: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/534#issuecomment-321239908

Comment: No, it should not vary based on OS... I'm still of the opinion your database is truncating it. Can you check what yours is generating, what it stores in the database, and what the database actually stores? O_o

Comment: @CodyG., you was right, db somehow truncate hash data. Please add your comment as answer.

Comment: Done. Glad it was simple! Hopefully you can figure out why its truncating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the database is not truncating the data. The hash should generally be 60 characters, not 50 from:

```
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
```

Tested:
https://repl.it/@CodyGeisler/bcrypt-test?language=nodejs